# Python Filling Up Disk

Tags: python, hard-drive

I need to setup some test conditions to simulate a filled up disk. I created the following to simply write garbage to the disk:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import mmap

def freespace(p):
    """
    Returns the number of free bytes on the drive that ``p`` is on
    """
    s = os.statvfs(p)
    return s.f_bsize * s.f_bavail 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    drive_path = sys.argv[1]
    output_path = sys.argv[2]

    output_file = open(output_path, 'w')

    while freespace(drive_path) > 0:
        output_file.write("!")
        print freespace(drive_path)
        output_file.flush()

    output_file.close()
```

As far as I can tell by looking at the return value from freespace, the write method does not write the file to until it is closed, thereby making the while condition invalid.

Is there a way I can write the data directly to the file? Or another solution perhaps?

Comment: Try `os.fsync` to write changes and wait for it

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Filling up a disk one character at a time is going to take _guite_ a while, you know (unless it's already almost full).

Comment: Yea, especially flushing it each time. Much better off writing MBs at a time, then backing off when you start getting errors by only writing half the amount as previously to fill the last bit.

Comment: You could use `dd` instead of writing your own script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested but I imagine something along these lines will be the quickest way to fill the disk easily

```
import sys
import errno

write_str = "!"*1024*1024*5  # 5MB

output_path = sys.argv[1]

with open(output_path, "w") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            f.write(write_str)
            f.flush()
        except IOError as err:
            if err.errno == errno.ENOSPC:
                write_str_len = len(write_str)
                if write_str_len > 1:
                    write_str = write_str[:write_str_len/2]
                else:
                    break
            else:
                raise
```

Comment: this needs an `import sys`

Answer (score 0):

You could try/catch a disk full exception on write.